# Determining number of infinite elements and their positions in a matrix

Tags: r

I want to determine number of infinite elements and their positions in a matrix using R. Let m is such a 2x4 matrix:

```
4  inf  12   6
1  8    inf  42
```

Obvioulsy there are 2 infinite elements in m. And their positions are 1,2 and 2,3.

How can I find these using R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# Let m be a matrix of interest
which(is.infinite(m), arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   2
[2,]   2   3
```

Explanation:

- [`base::is.infinite`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/is.finite) returns `TRUE` for elements that are infinitive
- `arr.ind` in `which` returns array indices for those infinite elements in matrix `m`

Comment: +1 and more accurately, arr.ind returns array indices where the first argument evaluates to TRUE, right?